# how to change html content text <p> using css

Tags: html, css, onclick

I want to know if it is possible to change the text of a `<p>` using the CSS onclick event. I know it is possible using Javascript. I just want to know if there is a way to do it in CSS.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS onclick event.

Comment: It's not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may emulate *simular* behaviour with using checkboxes and sibling selectors.

Just try SO snippet:

```css
[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  top: -9999px;
}
label > p {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
label > p:last-child {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ p {
  display: block;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <p>Click to format disk C:/</p>
  <p>Disk C:/ was succesfully formatted :) Oh no, click to restore!!!</p>
</label>
```

More links about used selectors:

1. [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
2. [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)